# how to access class' attribute instead of objects

Tags: python-3.x, class, metaprogramming

suppose you have

```
class c:
    pass
print(c.__call__)

output: <method-wrapper '__call__' of type object at 0x0000023378F28DC8>
```

my problem is I cannot get the same output if `__call__` is defined
like so:

```
class c:
    __call__ = lambda self: None
print(c.__call__)

output: <function c.<lambda> at 0x000002337A069B70>
```

and neither `type.__getattribute__(c, '__call__')` works

to conclude, I want first output in both examples
is it possible (I guess through some metaprogramming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same issue you could have with a class variable and an instance variable with the same name:

```
class Test:
    var = 1             # class variable

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 2    # instance variable with the same name

t = Test()
print(t.var)     # prints 2, the instance variable, not the class variable
print(Test.var)  # prints 1, the class variable
```

In your first exmaple, the `__call__` method is defined in the metaclass, `type`. You're accessing it though an instance of `type`, the class `c`. If you define a class variable in `c`, it's essentially an instance variable in the metaclass perspective, so you can't see the version defined in the metaclass any more.

As in my class variable code above, the best way to get the `__call__` method from the metaclass is to name it directly directly: `type.__call__`. If you think you might have some other metaclass, you could call `type` on the class, to get the metaclass without naming it: `type(c).__call__`.

Note that the `type.__call__` method gets run in different situations than a `__call__` method defined in a normal class. The interpreter runs `type.__call__` when you call the class, e.g. `c()`, while `c.__call__` gets run when you call an instance:

```
obj = c()  # this is type.__call__
obj()      # this is where c.__call__ runs
```